# Apache Airflow: After pointing airflow.cfg to postgres, it still tries to run on MySQL

Tags: celery, airflow

I'm using [Apache-airflow2](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow). My dags were running on `LocalExecutor` up until now smoothly. Now i want to scale it up and use `CeleryExecutor` (I'm still doing it on my Local Mac) I've configured it to run on CeleryExecutor, and when server starts, the log shows CeleryExecutor. But whenever i run airflow worker(so the same can be used as worker), or airflow flower, I run into an error where it tries to connect to Mysqlite and fails when it doesn't find the module.

I've configured `rabbitMQ` on local and airflow on `virtualenv`. Find below updated lines in airflow.cfg:

```
broker_url = amqp://myuser:mypassword@localhost/myvhost
result_backend = db+postgresql://localhost:5433/celery_space?user=celery_user&password=celery_user
sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql://localhost:5433/postgres?user=postgres&password=root
executor = CeleryExecutor
```

Please find below worker error:

```
 -------------- celery@superadmins-MacBook-Pro.local v4.2.1 (windowlicker)
---- **** ----- 
--- * ***  * -- Darwin-18.2.0-x86_64-i386-64bit 2018-12-30 09:15:00
-- * - **** --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         airflow.executors.celery_executor:0x10c682fd0
- ** ---------- .> transport:   sqla+mysql://airflow:airflow@localhost:3306/airflow
- ** ---------- .> results:     mysql://airflow:**@localhost:3306/airflow
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 16 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> default          exchange=default(direct) key=default


[tasks]
  . airflow.executors.celery_executor.execute_command

[2018-12-30 09:15:00,290: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to sqla+mysql://airflow:airflow@localhost:3306/airflow
[2018-12-30 09:15:00,304: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: ModuleNotFoundError("No module named 'MySQLdb'")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/deepaksaroha/Desktop/apache_2.0/nb-atom-airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 205, in start
    self.blueprint.start(self)
  File "/Users/deepaksaroha/Desktop/apache_2.0/nb-atom-airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 119, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/Users/deepaksaroha/Desktop/apache_2.0/nb-atom-airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 369, in start
    return self.obj.start()
  File "/Users/deepaksaroha/Desktop/apache_2.0/nb-atom-airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 317, in start
    blueprint.start(self)
  File "/Users/deepaksaroha/Desktop/apache_2.0/nb-atom-airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 119, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/Users/deepaksaroha/Desktop/apache_2.0/nb-atom-airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/tasks.py", line 41, in start
    c.connection, on_decode_error=c.on_decode_error,
  File "/Users/deepaksaroha/Desktop/apache_2.0/nb-atom-airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/app/amqp.py", line 297, in TaskConsumer
    **kw
  File "/Users/deepaksaroha/Desktop/apache_2.0/nb-atom-airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 386, in __init__
    self.revive(self.channel)
  File "/Users/deepaksaroha/Desktop/apache_2.0/nb-atom-airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 408, in revive
    self.declare()
  File "/Users/deepaksaroha/Desktop/apache_2.0/nb-atom-airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 421, in declare
    queue.declare()
  File "/Users/deepaksaroha/Desktop/apache_2.0/nb-atom-airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/entity.py", line 608, in declare
    self._create_queue(nowait=nowait, channel=channel)
  File "/Users/deepaksaroha/Desktop/apache_2.0/nb-atom-airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/entity.py", line 617, in _create_queue
    self.queue_declare(nowait=nowait, passive=False, channel=channel)
  File "/Users/deepaksaroha/Desktop/apache_2.0/nb-atom-airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/entity.py", line 652, in queue_declare
    nowait=nowait,
  File "/Users/deepaksaroha/Desktop/apache_2.0/nb-atom-airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/virtual/base.py", line 531, in queue_declare
    self._new_queue(queue, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/deepaksaroha/Desktop/apache_2.0/nb-atom-airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 82, in _new_queue
    self._get_or_create(queue)
  File "/Users/deepaksaroha/Desktop/apache_2.0/nb-atom-airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 70, in _get_or_create
    obj = self.session.query(self.queue_cls) \
  File "/Users/deepaksaroha/Desktop/apache_2.0/nb-atom-airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 65, in session
    _, Session = self._open()
  File "/Users/deepaksaroha/Desktop/apache_2.0/nb-atom-airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 56, in _open
    engine = self._engine_from_config()
  File "/Users/deepaksaroha/Desktop/apache_2.0/nb-atom-airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 51, in _engine_from_config
    return create_engine(conninfo.hostname, **transport_options)
  File "/Users/deepaksaroha/Desktop/apache_2.0/nb-atom-airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 425, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/deepaksaroha/Desktop/apache_2.0/nb-atom-airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 81, in create
    dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
  File "/Users/deepaksaroha/Desktop/apache_2.0/nb-atom-airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqldb.py", line 102, in dbapi
    return __import__('MySQLdb')
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
[2018-12-30 09:15:00,599] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
Starting flask
```

Please let know how can worker be run in sync with the airflow.cfg settings. Appreciate any help, let me know if anything further log or any configuration file is needed.

Comment: After changing the airflow.cfg, have you restarted your airflow webserver?

Comment: Yes, I did restart server, scheduler and worker.

Comment: `grep "sqla+mysql" /Users/deepaksaroha/Desktop/apache_2.0/ -R` - it is likely you're running with a different config file, or there are multiple values in the config file. Also, make sure you do have an AIRFLOW environment variable set somehow; refer to the docs.

Comment: @NinoWalker Cool! This actually helped. I had AIRFLOW_HOME configured on 1st run but, missed to add it to .rc files. Defining it, solved the issue. Thanks!